# ember firebase deploy -- events.js:85 -- throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event -- Error: spawn

Tags: ember.js, firebase

I'm following the directions from [Here](http://kerrygallagher.co.uk/deploying-an-ember-cli-application-to-firebase/) to set up a new firebase hosted app. I get to the end of the instructions and the 'ember firebase deploy' command fails. Here are the steps I'm taking:

```
C:\workspace\npm install -g firebase-tools
C:\workspace\cd dashdash
C:\workspace\dashdash\firebase login
C:\workspace\dashdash\npm install --save-dev ember-cli-firebase-hosting
C:\workspace\dashdash\ember generate firebase-hosting
C:\workspace\dashdash\ember firebase deploy
```

It works fine up until the last step. Instead of getting a `success` message and the `URL` of my `app`, I get the following:

```
C:\workspace\dashdash>ember firebase deploy
version: 1.13.8
Built project successfully. Stored in "dist".
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: spawn C:\workspace\dashdash\node_modules\ember-cli-firebase-hosting\node_modules\firebase-tools\bin\firebase ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I haven't changed the `app` in any way when I get to that step, and I can serve it successfully to `http://localhost:4200/` and get the `"Welcome to Ember"` message.

I'm running `Windows 7 Professional (SP1)` and using `Windows PowerShell` (run as administrator) to give the commands. I've also tried in `PHPStorm's terminal`.

I'm just learning about `Ember`, so if I've left something out (I probably have,) let me know. I'm more than happy to gather any necessary information. Any help/advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Here are my versions:

PS C:\workspace\dashdash> ember --version
version: 1.13.8
node: 0.12.7
npm: 2.13.4
os: win32 x64
PS C:\workspace\dashdash>

Answer (score 0):

After emailing Firebase support, I was able to get the app deployed using "firebase deploy" rather than "ember firebase deploy."